# Check whether output is smaller than input? (ffmpeg conversion with batch)

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, compression, png, exiftool

I've made a batch file that's able to compress many `png` files (with `ffmpeg`) as well as remove any unneeded metadata (using `exiftool`).

```
@echo off
title Compress png to png
color 08

FOR %%a IN (*.png) DO (

echo Compressing: %%~na

exiftool "%%a" -all= -overwrite_original

ffmpeg -i "%%a" "converted\%%~na.png"

del "%%a"
)
```

This results in up to 60x smaller file sizes! (In small png icons at least)

[image]

Unfortunately sometimes the compression with `ffmpeg` does not actually reduce file size, but rather increase it—especially when the image is larger—Which ruins the whole purpose of this process.

So I wonder whether there is a way to check the output (once compressed by `ffmpeg`) and see whether it's smaller in size than the input. And then act accordingly.

Like this...

```
@echo off
title Compress png to png
color 08

FOR %%a IN (*.png) DO (

echo Compressing: %%~na

exiftool "%%a" -all= -overwrite_original

ffmpeg -i "%%a" "converted\%%~na.png"



CHECK:  Is compressed file smaller in size than "%%a" ?

If not, then delete converted\%%~na.png, and move* "%%a" in \converted

If it is, then just delete "%%a"


del "%%a"
)
```

**[Download requires files, if you wanna test it and figure it out (22.7MB)](https://www.mediafire.com/file/8cpo0j6mjahm7qa/ffmpeg%252C_exiftool%252C_batchpng.7z/file)**

Also let me know whether there is a better way to do all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some PowerShell logic that only performs a copy operation if the new file is smaller than the original file that I've used for `jpg` files in the past.

This also resets the new smaller file to the original file's `CreationTime`, `LastWriteTime`, and `LastAccessTime` essentially preserving that metadata as part of the process.

I've made some adjustments based on your comments for your specific needs. I've also included a batch script example for it to execute the PowerShell script as you need once extracted.

### Execute PowerShell via batch

<sub>**Note:** This is the batch script extracted to double click to execute the PS script extracted to the same location.</sub>

```
SET PSScriptName=Compress.ps1
CD /D "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "%~dp0%PSScriptName%"
```

### PowerShell

```
$scriptPath = (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent);
$imagelocation = "$scriptPath";
$convertedlocation = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Temp";
If(!(Test-Path $convertedlocation)){New-Item -Path $convertedlocation -ItemType Directory -Force;};
 
$src  = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$imagelocation\" -File | ? {$_.extension -match ".jpg|.jpeg|.jfif"};
$dest = $convertedlocation;
$originals = "$scriptPath\_originals";
If(!(Test-Path "$($originals)")){New-Item -Path "$($originals)" -ItemType Directory -Force;};
 
$scnt = $src.count;
$cnt  = 0;
 
Write-Host "LOSSY COMPRESSION" -ForegroundColor Gray;

$src | % { Process {
 
        $cnt += 1;
        $sz = [math]::round(($_.Length / 1MB),2);
 
        If($_.extension -match ".jpg|.jpeg|.jfif"){ 
 
            If(Test-Path "$($originals)"){Copy-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination "$originals\$($_.basename)$($_.Extension)_original" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue};
 
            Start-Process exiftool -WorkingDirectory $scriptPath -ArgumentList "`"$($_.FullName)`" -all= -overwrite_original" -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden;
            Start-Process ffmpeg -WorkingDirectory $scriptPath -ArgumentList "-i `"$($_.FullName)`" `"$($dest)\$($_.Basename).jpg`"" -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden;
 
            $osize = "";
            $dsize = "";
            $osize = (Get-Childitem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Length;
            $dsize = (Get-Childitem -LiteralPath "$($dest)\$($_.Basename).jpg" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Length;
            $nsz = [math]::round(($dsize / 1MB),2)
            $osz = [math]::round(($osize / 1MB),2)
 
            If($osize -gt $dsize){    
                $ct = $_.CreationTime;
                $wt = $_.LastWriteTime;
                $at = $_.LastAccessTime;
 
                Copy-Item -LiteralPath "$($dest)\$($_.Basename).jpg" -Destination "$($_.Directory.FullName)\$($_.Basename).jpg" -Force;
 
                Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath "$($_.Directory.FullName)\$($_.Basename).jpg" -Name CreationTime   -Value $ct;
                Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath "$($_.Directory.FullName)\$($_.Basename).jpg" -Name LastWriteTime  -Value $wt;
                Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath "$($_.Directory.FullName)\$($_.Basename).jpg" -Name LastAccessTime -Value $at;
 
                Write-Host "$cnt of $scnt from $osz MB to $nsz MB ==> $($_.Directory.FullName)\$($_.Basename).jpg" -ForegroundColor Green;
 
                If(Test-Path "$($scriptPath)\$($_.Basename).jpeg"){Remove-Item -Path "$($scriptPath)\$($_.Basename).jpeg" -Force};
                If(Test-Path "$($scriptPath)\$($_.Basename).jfif"){Remove-Item -Path "$($scriptPath)\$($_.Basename).jfif" -Force};
 
                Remove-Item -LiteralPath "$($dest)\$($_.Basename).jpg" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
                } Else { Remove-Item -LiteralPath "$($dest)\$($_.Basename).jpg" ; Write-Host "$cnt of $scnt orig size $osz MB smaller than new size $nsz MB ==> $($_.Directory.FullName)\$($_.Basename).jpg" -ForegroundColor Yellow; }
            };
    }};
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2)

  - > `Get-ChildItem` usually returns a `FileInfo` object. Those objects
    > contain a few useful properties—among them are...
    >
    > - the full path, file name, and extension (`FullName`),
    > - the path alone (`DirectoryName`),
    > - the file name (`Name`), and
    > - the file name without its extension (`BaseName`)
    >
    > [Source](https://4sysops.com/archives/split-path-get-childitem-splitting-file-names-in-powershell/)
- [about_Assignment_Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.2)
- [Start-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.2)
- [Math.Round Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0)
- [If](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [Copy-Item](https://ss64.com/ps/copy-item.html)
- [Remove-Item](https://ss64.com/ps/remove-item.html)
- [Set-ItemProperty](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.2)
- [PowerShell Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)

Comment: @goldnick7 My apologies for taking so long to get back, but I just tested and figured out the issue. Basically the `Start-Process` command needs to contain the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter which I pointed to the `$ScriptPath` location and then everything worked without any issue from a machine with a limited user permission in my test environment. There are only two lines of code to change or replace rather which I pasted here: https://pastebin.com/1bj6iJQh. You just need to replace the two `Start-Process` lines executing `exiftool` and `ffmpeg` with that code.

Comment: I also added the `-ArgumentList` parameter for consistency and completeness sake, and I moved the hidden and other parameters to the end of the commands. If you tell me this works and send me a download link to the files, I'll be happy to update with the final working code too.

Comment: Tested it on 2 computers and It all works! No errors! You can download the files [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/yjf8jx9p6bdrkt6/ImgFix.7z/file) .. also I made [these instructions](https://tinyurl.com/22dtuypb)

Comment: I have found a way todo all this with `batch` alone, so personally I will not be using these powershell scripts. I have also found much better tools to compress images than ffmpeg and exiftool. I'll let you know when the scripts are ready and I'll probably make instructions for that also.